# Python RQ (Redis Queue) - are there NodeJS compatible versions?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'd like to write a lambda function using NodeJS whereas a colleague of mine wants to use Python. We're using Redis and a task queue via RQ (see title). Is there a way I can access the Redis queue from NodeJS? If so, what package would I use to do this?

Because task queues are software repos that use a message broker, I'm thinking a package like RQ for python would be available for many languages.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it will be difficult because you will have to read Python RQ's implementation to understand what kind of data you need to maintain whene pushing / pulling from the queue as well as job status, etc...

Comment: In this case, I just want to send a message from NodeJS.

Comment: If so, I suggest you setup Python RQ and enable monitor on local redis to watch for any change. do a simple message publishing from Python side and see what they do. You can then write a simple client in Node.js to do the same.